# Getting the header row and table data to move in harmony with the horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I need your help.

How can the HTML/CSS coding be modified, so as to allow, when a user scrolls horizontally left and right, that the columns and data move in sync  with it. Right now, when the user slides the horizontal bar back and fourth, my columns do not line up properly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Upgrade MSIE5.5-8 to be compatible with modern browsers -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>

/* ----- Scrolling Table ----- */
.dataGridHeader {
position:relative;
padding-top:24px;

border-left: 1px solid #999;
border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

.dataGridContent {
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:scroll;
height:144px;
}

.dataGridHeader thead tr {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}

.dataGridHeader table thead tr th, .dataGridHeader table tbody tr td { 
text-align:left;
height:0;
}

table.scrolltablestyle {
    border-top: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 1100px;
}

table.scrolltablestyle tbody tr td{
    background: #fff;
    text-align:left;
    padding: 4px 9px;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
}
table.scrolltablestyle thead tr th{
    background-color: #FFFFD9;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align:left;
    padding: 4px 9px 4px 9px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

table.scrolltablestyle thead tr th {
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
}

table.scrolltablestyle tbody tr td{
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
        width: 200px;
}


table.scrolltablestyle tbody tr:last-child td{
    border-bottom: 0;
}



</style>



</head>
<body>

<div class="dataGridHeader">
  <div class="dataGridContent">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="scrolltablestyle">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Shopper Name</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>User ID</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>TestColumn</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>C2C Fishing</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>C2C Fishing</td>
    <td>Enabled</td>
    <td>Enabled</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C2C Fishing</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>C2C Fishing</td>
    <td>Enabled</td>
    <td>Enabled</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>C2C Fishing</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>C2C Fishing</td>
    <td>Enabled</td>
    <td>Enabled</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>C2C Fishing</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>C2C Fishing</td>
    <td>Enabled</td>
    <td>Enabled</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>C2C Fishing</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>C2C Fishing</td>
    <td>Enabled</td>
    <td>Enabled</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>C2C Fishing</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>C2C Fishing</td>
    <td>Enabled</td>
    <td>Enabled</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>C2C Fishing</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>C2C Fishing</td>
    <td>Enabled</td>
    <td>Enabled</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>C2C Fishing</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>C2C Fishing</td>
    <td>Enabled</td>
    <td>Enabled</td>
  </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Jhon just remove the `position:absolute` from this class

```
.dataGridHeader thead tr
{
/*position:absolute;*/ //* this is the problem*/
}
```

Comment: @jhonSmith today i think we will work together. this is my second answer for you in just 20 mins :) :D

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the OP's code, it appears that the intention was to create a table with a vertically-fixed header row and scrolling body. Almost all of the pure CSS scrolling table designs I've seen that have a fluid width have the same problem: when scrolling sideways, the column headers don't stay with the columns. The accepted answer does solve this problem, but it also disables the vertically-fixed header, essentially turning this into a standard table.

For a solution that keeps the vertically-fixed header while also allowing proper horizontal scrolling, look here: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doctorDestructo/kn4xprgx/)**

The code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="scrollingtable">
  <div>
    <div>
      <table>
        <caption>Top Caption</caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><div label="Column 1"/></th>
            <th><div label="Column 2"/></th>
            <th><div label="Column 3"/></th>
            <th>
              <!--more versatile way of doing column label; requires 2 identical copies of label-->
              <div><div>Column 4</div><div>Column 4</div></div>
            </th>
            <th class="scrollbarhead"/> <!--ALWAYS ADD THIS EXTRA CELL AT END OF HEADER ROW-->
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    Faux bottom caption
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**CSS**

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]><style>.scrollingtable > div > div > table {margin-right: 17px;}</style><![endif]-->
<style>
/*the following html and body rule sets are required only if using a % width or height*/
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.scrollingtable {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto; /*if you want a fixed width, set it here, else set to auto*/
  min-width: /*0*/100%; /*if you want a % width, set it here, else set to 0*/
  height: 188px/*100%*/; /*set table height here; can be fixed value or %*/
  min-height: 0/*104px*/; /*if using % height, make this large enough to fit scrollbar arrows + caption + thead*/
  font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0; /*need enough padding to make room for caption*/
  text-align: left;
}
.scrollingtable * {box-sizing: border-box;}
.scrollingtable > div {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px; /*this determines column header height*/
}
.scrollingtable > div:before {
  top: 0;
  background: cornflowerblue; /*header row background color*/
}
.scrollingtable > div:before,
.scrollingtable > div > div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div {
  min-height: 0/*43px*/; /*if using % height, make this large enough to fit scrollbar arrows*/
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: /*scroll*/auto; /*set to auto if using fixed or % width; else scroll*/
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black; /*border around table body*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div:after {background: white;} /*match page background color*/
.scrollingtable > div > div > table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-top: -20px; /*inverse of column header height*/
  margin-right: 17px; /*uncomment if using % width*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px; /*inverse of caption height*/
  margin-top: -1px; /*inverse of border-width*/
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > * > tr > * {padding: 0;}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 6px 0 6px; /*header cell padding*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > :first-child:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px; /*match column header height*/
  border-left: 1px solid black; /*leftmost header border*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div[label]:before,
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div > div:first-child,
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * + :before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  color: white; /*header row font color*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div[label]:before,
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div[label]:after {content: attr(label);}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * + :before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  min-height: 20px; /*match column header height*/
  padding-top: 1px;
  border-left: 1px solid black; /*borders between header cells*/
}
.scrollingtable .scrollbarhead {float: right;}
.scrollingtable .scrollbarhead:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  top: -1px; /*inverse border-width*/
  background: white; /*match page background color*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr:after {
  content: "";
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  top: -1px; /*inverse of border width*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody {vertical-align: top;}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr {background: white;}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr > * {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 6px 0 6px;
  height: 20px; /*match column header height*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody:last-of-type > tr:last-child > * {border-bottom: none;}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {background: gainsboro;} /*alternate row color*/
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr > * + * {border-left: 1px solid black;} /*borders between body cells*/
</style>
```

---